# Link function not getting run in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm having trouble with an angular directive. It doesn't seem to run the link function.

I feel like it's something obvious, but I just can't figure it out.

The directive is required as seen from below

```
angular.module('test').requires // ["injectedModule"]
```

Code below. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch3safka/1/).

Any help would be amazing.

```js
angular
    .module('test', ['injectedModule'])
    .controller('tester', [
        function() {
            this.test = function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    ]);

angular
    .module('injectedModule', [])
    .directive('testing', [
      function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: true,
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            alert(scope, element, attrs);
          }
        };
      }
    ]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="tester as t">
         <video id="test" ng-src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t50.2886-16/11726387_1613973172221601_1804343601_n.mp4" testing="t.test(el)" />        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like

```
restrict: 'E',
```

should be

```
restrict: 'A',
```

Your directive isn't being called at all as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the restriction you are giving to your directive.
You are restricting your directive to match only element (in other words tag). You should restrict to match attribute 'A'. Here's angular official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
and here's your [fiddle working](https://jsfiddle.net/fL19kso3/1/)

Code sample:

```
angular
.module('injectedModule', [])
.directive('testing', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        alert(scope, element, attrs);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```